# Unresponsive page layout with ReactMapGL in ReactJs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a ReactMapGL component in my page that is stored above the footer and below the navbar. In my initial screen from my desktop the layout looks fine, but when I inspect element to make the screen size smaller, the layout becomes unresponsive.

[image]

So far this is my code for this particular page:

```
export default function Map({posts}) {
    const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
        latitude: 45.4211,
        longitude: -75.6938,
        width:"100vw",
        height:"100vh",
        zoom: 10,
    });

    const [selectedProperty, setSelectedProperty] = useState(null)

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactMapGL {...viewport} mapboxApiAccessToken="//mykey"
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/jay/cks5xkaa892cp17o5hyxcuu0z"
        onViewportChange={viewport => {
            setViewport(viewport);
        }}>
        {
          posts &&
          posts.map((maps) => (
            <Marker key={maps.id} latitude={maps.Latitude} longitude={maps.Longitude}>
                <button className="marker-btn" onClick={e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    setSelectedProperty(maps);
                }}>
                    <img src="placeholder.svg"/>
                </button>
            </Marker>
          ))}

          {selectedProperty ? (
              <Popup latitude={selectedProperty.Latitude} longitude={selectedProperty.Longitude} 
              onClose={() => {setSelectedProperty(null);}}>
                <h1>{selectedProperty.Title}</h1>
              </Popup>) : null}
        </ReactMapGL> 
      </div>
    );
}
```

For the Navbar and footer I have copy pasted the html and css from [here](https://www.codingnepalweb.com/responsive-navigation-menu-bar-design/).